# jQuery doesn't returns the new data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying a very simple task working with data-attr and jQuery, check this example:

**Markup**:

```
<div data-name="Testing"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var div = $('div');
    $(div).append($(div).data('name'));
    $(div).attr('data-name', ' -  Testing 2');
    $(div).append($(div).data('name'));
    console.log(div);
});
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/YsKJJ/16/

So, it should appends inside the `div` the text `Testing - Testing 2`, but prints `TestingTesting`. In console I checked if the attr was changed in the object, and yes, has the new value `- Testing 2` but jQuery still returns the original value :(

Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

So, the reason of this behavior according jQuery docs:

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is
>   accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values
>   are then stored internally in jQuery).

More information: [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Comment: `$(div).data('name', ' -  Testing 2');` - also, don't use data attributes unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: That is the way data api works. You need to set it with data-api itself.

Comment: @SalmanA yes, I just realized of that.

Comment: Just remember this: element data values are *in memory* and are only initially, if needed, pulled from the value of the corresponding data-attribute. Attributes, on the other hand, are always reflected *in the DOM*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/DDv8U/

- API: http://api.jquery.com/data/ - try using this `$(div).data('name', ' -  Testing 2');`

rest should fit the need `:)`

**code**

```
$(function(){
    var div = $('div');
    $(div).append($(div).data('name'));
    $(div).data('name', ' -  Testing 2');
    $(div).append($(div).data('name'));
});
```

Comment: So, I can't mix `data()` and `attr()` :)

Comment: Correct, they are two different things. The first time you use .data, jquery will pull all data attributes from the element and stick it in the data object. From then on, it will only look at the data object.

Comment: @zyztema yep you can't `:)` if you keen read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Tats_innit I just edited my question pointing to that question!

Comment: @zyztema Glad it helped `:)` oh nice +1 to your question!

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the attribute but this doesn't automatically update the data. This works:

```
$(function(){
    var div = $('div');
    div.append(div.data('name'));
    div.data('name', ' -  Testing 2');
    div.append(div.data('name'));
});
```